# Memory allocation for Data segment not happening properly for each static and global(uninitialized/ initialized variable)

Tags: c, ipc, data-segment

I am trying to understand how memory allocation works for any C code which is executed or compiled.

I have written following 5 separate small codes which will help me understand the memory allocation process.

1. segment_size1.c

   ```
   int main(){
       printf("hellow world");
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. segment_size2.c

   ```
   //Adding uninitialized static int variable This would increase the size of BSS by 4 bytes.
   int main()
   {
       static int mystatic;
       printf("Hellow world");
       return 0;
   }
   ```
3. segment_size3.c

   ```
   // Adding initialized static int variable, this would increase the size of initialized data
   // segment by 4 bytes.

   int main()
   {
           static int mystatic;
           static int mystatic1 = 100;
           printf("Hellow world");
           return 0;
   }
   ```
4. segment_size4.c

   ```
   // Adding un-initialized global int variable, this would increase the size of BSS segment by 4 bytes.

   int myglobal;
   int main()
   {
           static int mystatic;
           static int mystatic1 = 100;
           printf("Hellow world");
           return 0;
   }
   ```
5. segment_size5.c

   ```
   // Adding initialized global int variable, this would increase the size of data segment by 4 bytes.

   int myglobal;
   int myglobal2 = 500;
   int main()
   {
       static int mystatic;
       static int mystatic1 = 100;
       printf("Hellow world");
       return 0;
   }
   ```

According to my understanding, if we compile above files then after compiling segment_size2.c BSS size should get incremented by 4 bytes and after compiling segment_size3.c Data size should get incremented by 4 bytes. 
But when I hit size command, I got following results,

```
    size segment_size1 segment_size2 segment_size3 segment_size4 segment_size5
       text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
       1217     560       8    1785     6f9 segment_size1
       1217     560       8    1785     6f9 segment_size2
       1217     564      12    1793     701 segment_size3
       1217     564      12    1793     701 segment_size4
       1217     568      16    1801     709 segment_size5
```

Here We can clearly see that bss and data segment is simultaneously getting updated after compiling segment_size3. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> We can clearly see that bss and data segment is simultaneously getting updated

This is the distinction between where the initial values != 0 are saved and where the static/global variables are

Before the *main* execution the initial values !=0 are copied into the global/static variables, the global/static variables having the initial value 0 are also set to 0 of course